# IE10 - tables - alignment not working

Tags: html, html-table, internet-explorer-10

Since I upgraded to IE10, tables on my webpage are not shown correctly. Below is the example:

[image]

The head section of the table is shown correctly but it seems like the whole body of the table is put in one (left) column or cell.

I searched for the solution, but I didn't find anything useful yet.

Here is the code:

```
<table class="class" id="id">
<colgroup>
<col width="" style="display:none;"  />
<col width="190" />
<col width="160" />
<col width="100" />
<col width="170" />
<col width="120" />
</colgroup>
<thead>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td>heading1</td>
<td>heading2</td>
<td>heading3</td>
<td>heading4</td>
<td>heading5</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody runat="server" id="tbody">
<tr>
<td style="display: none;">id</td>
<td><div style="float:left; width:15px; height:1.15em; text-align:right; padding-right:8px;"><img src="" alt="" title="" /></div><div style="clear:right; text-align:left; overflow:hidden;" title="">some value</div></td>
<td><div style="overflow: hidden; height:1.15em;" title="">some value</div></td>
<td><div style="overflow: hidden; height:1.15em;">some value</div></td>
<td><div style="overflow: hidden; height:1.15em;">some value</div></td>
<td><div style="overflow: hidden; height:1.15em;">some value</div></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: what's the result when you just delete all the css? maybe the float: left; is a problem.

Comment: do you not need to close your `colgroup` and you have 5 headings but six columns in the row below.  Also you `clear:right` when your float is left

Comment: Kees I removed all the css but it is still the same.

Comment: When I edited the code I deleted some of the marks. The code is definitely correct because it worked in all IE versions before 10 and it is working in Mozilla, Opera...

Comment: @Peter It's probably worth creating a jsFiddle to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: I just found this question searching for a similar problem: for me, IE10 is not aligning cells that have an explicit width set. Unless I disable that width and then reenable it in developer tools, then it aligns fine. Doesn't inspire confidence in what other bugs may be lurking.

Comment: Turns out my bug is unique to IE7 standards mode, which makes it more forgivable. It wasn't there in IE9 in IE7 standards mode, though. Ever wish you could just throw a legacy site away and rebuild it from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your markup shown is a tad invalid, as you're missing the opening `<tr>` tag in `<tbody>`. I would say IE10 is actually displaying *correctly*.

Comment: Tieson the code is correct but I just missed <tr> when I edited it.

Comment: Well, I see 5 "header" columns and 6 "data" columns - is that intentional? I'm not sure the spec defines how tables should handle cells that exist in markup but are hidden by CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The browser is behaving correctly. The [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html#columns) for col tag styles states that the only styles they support are `border`, `background`, `width` and `visibility`. You're using `display`, which is not supported. In your header row, the first cell is not explicitly set `display:none`, but in your content row it is.

Fortunately, there is a special value of `collapse` for the `visibility` style for columns (actually, the only permissible value for a col tag), which behaves in the same way as `display:none`. It [appears to work](http://jsfiddle.net/j67PD/2/) as you want it to.